# Licensing limitations for things produced using Mathematica?

Tags: licensing

Mathematica is a proprietary software produced by Wolfram Research. Does its status as a proprietary software affect how I can distribute, commercialize, or license the things I have produced using Mathematica?

Hypothetical examples of the "things":

- A map of the world or a chemical diagram produced using Mathematica, saved as a JPG file, and used on a website to promote commercial products.
- A Mathematica package that I charge clients to use.
- A library (written in Mathematica and compiled to C) that I charge clients to use.
- A GUI written in Mathematica that I charge clients to use.
- On my blog, I publish thousands of graphs of historical fundamentals data obtained using [FinancialData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html).

Are all of the above legal?

I am new to Mathematica. I am wondering if Mathamtica imposes any restrictions on the distribution, the commercialization, or the licensing of products produced using Mathematica. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is probably something best discussed with Wolfram themselves or solved by reading the End User License Agreement that comes with MMA (admittedly, I never read it). This would be essentially legal advice, so you want to be absolutely certain that the answers are entirely correct. Further, I believe the answers will depend on what version of MMA you purchased. There are restrictions on the student version that may not apply to the home version or enterprise version.

Comment: This is far too broad, and it conflates many issues, such as things that *you* created using Mathematica, or using curated data (which you did not create, you simply retrieved it). E.g. the satellite imagery comes with its own license, not from Wolfram, but from DigitalGlobe. But then you did not produce those images, and neither did Wolfram, so it does not match the title of your question. You are also conflating creating a library or including components that are necessary for it to run (such as the Wolfram runtime or the MathLink libs). Please ask about specific issues separately.